# Can two samples of 189 and 50 undergo independent samples t test?

Tags: t-test

I have taken two types of subjects related to two categories one has a sample size of 189 and other has 50...Can I apply independent samples T test on them ????

Comment: Why not? Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63856

Comment: If the sample sizes are so different the test is more sensitive to failure of the equal variance assumption; if the variances are similar, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The equality of sample numbers is not a requirement for T test at all, but both samples should be greater than 10 or 15. Considering your both sample sizes are greater than 25, you could even use Z test to compare normally distributed variables in them.