# Marketing Data with many zeros

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, zero-inflation, marketing

I am working on a marketing data which is a time series data with marketing spend done through different channels and revenue generated.

The data looks like this :
[image: DataSet Sample]

My data contains too many zeros (no spend at that particular time) and my spend vs channel1 looks like this :

[image: Spend Vs Channel1(Catalog)]

I want to develop a marketing mix model on this data set to understand the impact of various marketing spend on Sales and to predict future Sales and to optimize spend on different channels. How can I proceed analyzing the same. Can I transform variables and do a regression?

Comment: No matter what transformation you use, all the zeros will end up in the same place as all the other zeros. How would that help? You may want to have a model that deals with the x=0 case differently from the other x-values.

Comment: It is unclear what your intentions are.  Are you trying predict the effect of marketing efforts on revenue earned in a time series setting? Or something else.  I have seen this issue before with marketing data, but to proceed with a potential solution I would need to know more about your intentions.  Particularly, (1) are you looking to predict future revenue or marketing spending on the bases of past values, or (2) are you looking to find the causal effect of marketing on revenue, or(3) both or (4) neither?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld My intentions are both -> To predict future revenues as well as impact of various marketing spend on revenue.

Comment: Then the simplest thing you can do is a regression of the form $revenue_{t}=\beta_0+\beta_1I(market_t=0)+\beta_2market_t+\varepsilon_t$ where $t$ is an index for time and $I(market_t>0)$ is an indicator variable which is equal to 1 when  marketing expenses are positive and 0 otherwise.  There is obviously more you could do, such as adding nonlinear functions of marketing, other lags of marketing and revenue and other variables that you think might effect revenue (the last one is a really good idea!).

Comment: If you are looking to find the impact of marketing spending on revenue (rather than just predicting revenue better with market spending information) please keep the issue of  endogeneity in mind.  It's common to find a negative coefficient for marketing effect on revenue in these circumstances which makes little sense (we expect marketing efforts to boost revenue).  This often happens because firms increase there marketing efforts in response to sales falling.  In these situations, the OLS coefficients will be bias downward

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyBlumenfeld. I have attached the data for better understanding. Any more suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: See [Linear Regression With Groups vs. Points - Issue with Influence of Zeros](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/103823/17230) for an example of @Zachary's indicator variable method.

Comment: Anyway, you will end up using some kind of transformation to model that zeros: `(x+1)^.5`