# How to Include an Independent Variable with one-half 0s, one-half non-0 values

Tags: regression, categorical-data, negative-binomial-distribution, predictor

I am running a negative binomial regression. One of my independent variables is a measure of distance traveled - half of the observations are 0 because they do not travel, while the other half have a non-zero, positive value equal to the distance they travel.

What is the best way to include such a variable in a regression? I suspect that having 50% 0s in the independent variable makes it difficult if not wrong to interpret the coefficient if the variable is included as is. On the other hand, a simple dummy variable could fix the problem, but then measuring the effect of each unit of distance traveled would not be possible.

Is separating the observations into a 0 and non-0 group a legitimate solution? Such that the same regression is applied in both cases, except the non-0 group is applied the distance traveled variable which now would have no 0s.

I am especially concerned because the variable is still significant (p<0.05) besides this less-than-convincing negative, linear relationship. There appear to be 11 of 550 (2%) observations that are outliers (those above DIST of 8). Common sense is telling me to throw this variable out - is having 11 outliers like this acceptable?

[image]

Comment: A 0 could be thought of as a missing value - but again, this would eliminate half of the observations for the regression.

Comment: Besides the other problems that were mentioned in answer or comments, because y is also discrete you have a lot of overplotting at x=0 there. You can't see where the mean x is. You should either mark in the mean or jitter the values (at least in the y-direction, possibly also a little in the x-direction). [It still won't solve the problem that if you plot the raw data you're only looking at the marginal relationship rather than the conditional one.]

Comment: I've been meaning to learn how to jitter - especially useful for count data with few y values. Still a long way to go learning R.

Comment: try `plot(jitter(y)~x)` for starters. Then see the help on `jitter` for more control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessarily wrong to include the variable as is.

If you expect the relationship to be linear so that the effect of travelling 2 above the effect of travelling 0 is twice the effect of travelling 1 above the effect of travelling 0, then everything is fine.

However, if you want to consider the possibility that the 0-cases behave differently from an otherwise linear relationship, then put an indicator variable ("dummy") in for the zeros (or the non-zeros, it makes no difference to the fit, only the interpretation of the indicator) and also leave the travel variable in the model as-is.

Here's an illustration of the two possible expectations about the behavior I am discussing -- you'll have to imagine it as being conditional on any other predictor variables (independent variables):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very insightful answer. My scatter plot is, unfortunately, not as convincing. I have 11 points (out of 550 observations) that are outside the negative, linear relationship (outliers). However, I am surprised the significance of the distance variable is still relatively strong (p<0.05). Based on the scatter plot, given that there are 11 (2%) observations that are outliers, why would this variable still be significant? Is 2% simply an acceptable amount? I understand this may be an impossible question to answer without more info. Again, thanks for your help, regardless.

Comment: You have more predictors than this one, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have five predictors - perhaps the y of these outliers are better explained by another predictor, so the fact that they are outliers here is not relevant with respect to the overall model specification. I am lacking in theory of statistics, please accept my apology. I added the scatter plot above. Thanks again.

Comment: In my answer, I made it clear my plot relates to what you *expect* about the *conditional* relationship (i.e. what you understand about the relationship between variables holding other variables constant), but you're looking at  the marginal relationship in the data. You can't just plot y vs x and expect to see anything much of value, and if you do, you're using the data to generate a model, so if you use all the data to do that you'll impact your analysis (it affects the distribution of your estimates, standard errors and p-values). If you do it anyway, check (e.g. deviance) residuals vs x.

Comment: BTW, sorry - for my plot I was influenced by the `regression` tag instead of thinking about the mention of the count response; nevertheless the underlying idea (but adapted to your particular link function and the discrete nature of the response) still holds