# Unequal sample size one way ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test, sample-size, multiple-comparisons

I want to compare the means of X between BMI groups, but have unequal sample sizes between my groups.

```
group A (n=20, mean=16.2);
group B (n=90, mean=12.8);
group C (n=30, mean=10.8);
group D (n=8,  mean=11.2)
```

1. Can I use a one way ANOVA test when the sample sizes are extremely unequal?
2. I performed a one way ANOVA test. The results showed significant differences for A-B and A-C, but not A-D. However when I did paired t-test for A-D, the result was significant. Which part am I doing wrong, the one way ANOVA or the t-test? Is an ANOVA test valid in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a total N = 148, distributed into 4 groups.  If you had 37 in each group instead, you would have greater statistical power.  Otherwise, a one-way ANOVA is just as valid here as anywhere else (given that the normal assumptions are met).  (To understand this better, it may help to read my answer here: [How should one interpret the comparison of means from different sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31330/7290))  So to answer **1.** explicitly, *yes, you can use a one-way ANOVA when the sample sizes are extremely unequal*.

However, your description in **2.** seems odd to me, so let me add a few notes:

- If the groups (A through D) were formed by categorizing BMI (a continuous variable), you would be better off using regression with BMI as your predictor; categorizing continuous variables is not a good thing to do.
- It isn't clear what you mean when you say that A-B and A-C were significant, but A-D wasn't.  An ANOVA doesn't tell you that.  An ANOVA only tells you if there is a difference *somewhere* amongst your groups.  Did you run some post-hoc test to get those results?
- I don't see how you could have run a *paired* t-test to compare A and D when they do not have the same ns.  Did you mean an *un*paired t-test?  Under the assumption that you used some proper test for post-hoc comparisons with the ANOVA, that was probably the appropriate option as a t-test would not take into account that you have multiple comparisons, for example.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did post-hoc test (Tukey) after that.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case. The Tukey test is going to be a better approach than the t-tests.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and helpful link. By the way my mistake, I mentioned paired t-test, it's actually independent t-test..sorry. I did t-test bcz I think that the results of group A & D from ANOVA was a bit strange, since the mean for D is around the value for B and C, I suppose it's also significant. So since t-test result for A & D is significant, but ANOVA wasn't..I wonder is it possible that we'll get different result from ANOVA and t-test because of the sample size? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, @natsya, the post-hoc test has lower power due to the smaller sample size. W/ less data there is more uncertainty about the true value of the mean of D, so it's less significant.

Comment: BMI data is usually highly right skewed.  With such few data points in each group, you might want to consider a non-parametric test since your normality assumptions are likely not met.

Comment: @StatsStudent, from the description, I think BMI is the *predictor* (even though the OP referred to the response as "X", which is unusual).

Comment: @gung, thanks.  I missed that in the OP.  Of course, you are right.