# Two sample t test with one sample is large sample and one sample is small

Tags: regression, t-test, linear

How can I perform a two sample t-test if one sample is small (n<30) and one sample is large (n>30). The usual method is giving wrong results. What should I do?

Comment: welcome to the site. Indicate results/output.

Comment: This should work perfectly well so there may be a slip in your calculations. Please edit in how you know it is giving the wrong results.

Comment: I don't see a problem either but what do you mean by "giving the wrong results"?

Answer (score 0):

When you perform t test for unequal sample size, your test loses in strength. Maybe your p value doesn't express the "right" answer because of it. Please check other people's questions about it, as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/how-should-one-interpret-the-comparison-of-means-from-different-sample-sizes#31330).